# Error on adding an arbiter

Tags: replication, mongodb

Adding 5th node getting an error

"Our replica set configuration is invalid or does not include us

Presently all 4 nodes are healthy.

|  | node | arb1 | arb2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| rs1 | m1,m2,m2 | a1 |  |

when I try to add a2 both the arbiters will go unhealhty immediately whereas my arbiter is healhty on itself but not healthy in replica set.

|  | node | arb1 | arb2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| rs1 | m1,m2,m2 | a1 | a2 |

Error for arbiter in replica set -

a1 - `"lastHeartbeatMessage" : "Our replica set configuration is invalid or does not include us"`

a2 - `"lastHeartbeatMessage" : "Couldn't get a connection within the time limit"`

where,

m- data nodes

a- arbiters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replica set should have ONLY one arbiter and ONLY when there is an even number of data-bearing nodes.

Your replica set has already an odd number of data-bearing nodes (m1, m2, and m3), so there should not be any arbiters.

Those error messages means:

```
a1 - rs.conf() don't have that a1 node in the list of that replica sets' config, it may have wrong IP or port-number
a2 - there is firewall (or similar) what prevents connection with other RS nodes.
```

Comment: you are right it was a wrong name resolution

Answer (score 1):

Use bellow code before adding arbiter to cluster

```
db.adminCommand(
  {
    setDefaultRWConcern : 1,
    defaultWriteConcern: { w: 1 },
  }
)
```

After this add arbiter to cluster

```
rs.addArb("<private-ip>:27017")
```